# NodeJS behavior of exporting class object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to understand the behavior of exporting class object instead of class name. Please help me make understand. Example

```
class Util {
  method() {
    return "method";
  }
}

module.exports = new Util();
```

and then importing it like

```
import Util from 'Util';
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? What currently don't you understand about the code?

Comment: I am using  v12.18.0. I want to understand, how many times the object will be created? What is the difference between importing a class and creating an object in new file or directly creating object and exporting it?

Comment: How many times do you see when the code is run? Try using `console.log` to help

Comment: You're mixing [CJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (`module.exports =...`) and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (`import`). I suggest you pick one and use it consistently, not least because [you can't use `require` to import an ESM module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs).

Comment: I can see constructor is being called every time, invoke a endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to understand, how many times the object will be created?

Once, in the normal case. Modules are loaded and cached, and if they're imported by multiple other modules, those modules all see the same instance of the module doing the exporting.

When using CJS modules, the cache is [`require.cache`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) and you can clear a module from the cache by deleting the property for it from the `require.cache` object, meaning that it will get loaded fresh the next time it's `require`'d. (I don't think it's possible to do that with ESM modules.)

---

Note: You're mixing [CJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (`module.exports =...`) and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (`import`). I suggest you pick one and use it consistently, not least because [you can't use `require` to import an ESM module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs).

Comment: `Once, in the normal case. Modules are loaded and cached, and if they're imported by multiple other modules, those modules all see the same instance of the module doing the exporting.` - This is what, I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like, It is good way to use at places like services or helper or reusable kind of codes.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the class will let you create new instances using `new` on any other modules that `require`/`import` it.

```
import MyModule from 'module';

// when exporting class:
const mdl = new MyModule();

console.log(mdl.constructor === MyModule); // => true
console.log(mdl.myValue); // => 'test'
console.log(MyModule.myValue); // => undefined
```

Exporting the instance will only export a single object that has this class as prototype. Module caching/resolution will ensure the same object is returned and the value is not re-calculated when re-importing from different modules.

```
import MyModule from 'module';

// when exporting instance
const mdl = new MyModule(); // TypeError: MyModule is not a constructor
console.log(MyModule.myValue); // => 'test'
```

Comment: So, it acts like Bean or Services in Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the class syntax is just sugar on top of constructor functions.

If you export the `Util` "class", what you are exposing is that constructor function to be used with the `new Util()` syntax. Right?

In the other hand, if you export `new Util()`, instead of exporting the constructor function or the "class", you are exposing essentially an object constructed based on that constructor function's prototype object (or that "class") as it's prototype.

Comment: *"First of all, the class syntax is just sugar on top of constructor functions."* Just FWIW, that's no longer true now that these proposals are about to land: [1](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), [2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods), [3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features).